# Python 3.8.5 cv2 -215:Assertion failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, camera, opencv

> Error: Build\OpenCV\opencv-4.4.0\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Code:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
# Draw rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
# Display the output
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: If test.jpg exists and is not corrupt, then it is likely not in your current directory. So you probably need to provide the path to test.jpg in your cv2.imread() command.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when the image you are passing to it is empty i.e. OpenCV is not able to read the image.
Are you sure that the `test.jpg` is in the same directory as this code?

Check the extension. It might be `jpeg`.

You have two options -

1. Give the complete path in the `cv2.imread` function.
2. Move the image to the directory in which your code exists.